# checking for the correct number of characters in a java string

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to count the number of characters that occur in a java string.

For example:

given the poker hand 6s/3d/2H/13c/Ad

how many times does the / character occur? = 4

The user can enter a different hand with a changing number of card variables so hardcoding a method to check for occurrences isn't going to work.

A separator may be any one of: - / space (with only one separator type allowed to be used in one hand).
So I need to be able to check if either of the separators occurs 4 times otherwise the incorrect format has been given.

Here's a some java code to give a better idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
    String hand = "6s/1c/2H/13c/Ad";
    System.out.println("Original hand: " + hand);

    // split the hand string into individual cards
    String[] cards = hand.split(hand);

    // Checking for separators
    // Need to check for the correct number of separators
    if(hand.contains("/")){
        cards = hand.split("/");
    } else if (hand.contains("-")){
        cards = hand.split("-");
    } else if (hand.contains(" ")){
        cards = hand.split(" ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect format!");

    }
```

Any help would be great!

Also this is a school project/homework.

Edit 1--------------------------------------------------------

OK so here's my code after your suggestions

```
    String hand = "6s 1c/2H-13c Ad";
    System.out.println("Original hand: " + hand);

    // split the hand string into individual cards
    String[] cards = hand.split("[(//\\-\\s)]");

    if (cards.length != 5) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect format!");    
    } else {

        for (String card : cards) {
            System.out.println(card);
        }
    }
```

The given hand above is not in the correct format because the user can only use ONE type of separator for a given hand. For example:

- 6s/1c/2H/13c/Ad - correct
- 6s-1c-2H-13c-Ad - correct
- 6s 1c 2H 13c Ad - correct

How do I ensure that the user only uses ONE type of separator??

Cheers for the answers so far!

Edit 2 ------------------------------------------

So playing around with nested if statements my code now looks like this:

```
    String hand = "6s/1c/2H/13c/Ad";
    System.out.println("Original hand: " + hand);

    // split the hand string into individual cards

    if(hand.contains("/")){
        String[] cards = hand.split("/");
        if(cards.length != 5){
            System.out.println("Incorrect format! 1");
        } else {
            for (String card : cards) {
                System.out.println(card);
            }
        }

    } else if(hand.contains("-")){
        String[] cards = hand.split("-");
        if(cards.length != 5){
            System.out.println("Incorrect format! 2");
        } else {
            for (String card : cards) {
                System.out.println(card);
            }
        }

    } else if(hand.contains(" ")){
        String[] cards = hand.split(" ");
        if(cards.length != 5){
            System.out.println("Incorrect format! 3");
        } else {
            for (String card : cards) {
                System.out.println(card);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect format! 4");
    }
```

This way works as intended but is ugly!

Any suggestions would be great cheers.

Comment: As this is homework, just a hint. The `split` method allows for a regular expression, this might solve your problem. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to use regular expressions but it doesn't seem to work if the given hand is changed. For example the user may input AS/13D/JS/13S/AD this changes where the separators occur. But in saying this it could be the way i'm doing my regex. Cheers.

Comment: @user1575658 What regex have you tried?

Comment: Post your regex and then let SO assist you.

Comment: This is my regex [(//\\-\\s)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this before the first question edit, so I am responding to the original question and not its addendum question.

In the [documentation on String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), it is unclear whether empty strings count as substrings. Notice that `"--".split("-").length == 0`. The question may implicitly guarantee that two or more characters separate delimiters, but that is a risky assumption and where Java's String.split becomes problematic.

This is a partial simpler implementation:

```
    char[] delims = {'/', ' ', '-'};
    int result = 0;
    for (char delim : delims) {
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
            if (hand.charAt(i) == delim) {
                ++result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Full code follows, with editorial comments intended for homework.

```
interface Counter {
    int count(String hand);
}
class FirstCounter implements Counter {
    public int count(String hand) {
        String[] cards = hand.split(hand);
        if(hand.contains("/")){
            cards = hand.split("/");
        } else if (hand.contains("-")){
            cards = hand.split("-");
        } else if (hand.contains(" ")){
            cards = hand.split(" ");
        } else {
            // Prefer to fail fast unless your requirement
            // really is to only print "incorrect format"
            //System.out.println("Incorrect format!");
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect format!");
        }
        if (hand.endsWith("-") || hand.endsWith("/") || hand.endsWith(" ")) {
            return cards.length;
        }
        return cards.length - 1;
    }    
}
class SecondCounter implements Counter {
    public int count(String hand) {
        char[] delims = {'/', ' ', '-'};
        int result = 0;
        for (char delim : delims) {
            for (int i = 0; i < hand.length(); i++) {
                if (hand.charAt(i) == delim) {
                    ++result;
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == 0) {
            // This is a hack or inconsistent with requirements,
            // but necessary to match original posted code behavior
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect format!");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
class Main {
    private static int testCount = 0;

    static void realAssert(boolean condition) {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new AssertionError("Java has no real assert");
        }
    }

    static void test(Counter counter) {
        ++testCount;
        try {
            realAssert(counter.count("6s/3d/2H/13c/Ad") == 4);
            realAssert(counter.count("6s-3d-2H-13c-Ad") == 4);
            realAssert(counter.count("6s 3d 2H 13c Ad") == 4);
            // Don't forget boundary conditions
            realAssert(counter.count("6s-3d-2H-13c-") == 4);
            realAssert(counter.count("6s/3d/2H/13c/") == 4);
            realAssert(counter.count("6s 3d 2H 13c ") == 4);
            realAssert(counter.count("-6s-3d-2H-13c-") == 5);
            realAssert(counter.count("/6s/3d/2H/13c/") == 5);
            realAssert(counter.count(" 6s 3d 2H 13c ") == 5);
            realAssert(counter.count("--") == 2);
            // Remember to test error conditions
            try {
                counter.count("foobar");
                realAssert(false);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // Catching RuntimeException is normally bad
                // done only as example.
                // Also normally bad, this is an empty catch
                // block. These are sometimes useful, but always
                // at least add a comment that explains that this
                // catch block really should be empty, in this case
                // because the test was meant to throw an Error.
            }
            try {
                counter.count("foo/bar-baz");
                // Left as exercise for reader, based on question
                // it is possible this should be disallowed.
                //realAssert(false);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // Ditto above, intentionally empty catch
            }
            System.out.println("Test " + testCount + " succeeded");
        }
        catch (Error e) {
            // XXX: Don't catch Error in non-example code
            System.out.println("Test " + testCount + " failed");
            /* Normally don't use printStackTrace either */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(new FirstCounter());
        test(new SecondCounter());
    }
}
```

Just for education, the regular expression approach can be good. The entire solution takes one line of Ruby, `hand.split(/[\-\/ ]/, -1).length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Without giving away the answer, you want to specify the delimiter to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) such that the array of Strings returned looks like:

```
cards[0] = "6s"
cards[1] = "1c"
cards[2] = "2H"
.
.
.
```

In your particular hand String, you have a convenient separator for each card that you can use to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`

**Eg:**

```
String reg = new String();
String s = "hjhjhkello/hi"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(/-\\\\s)]");  // Will find for / or - or space
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()){

 reg = matcher.group());

}


String[] arr = hand.split(reg);
```

Comment: I believe we are not supposed to provide the complete answer for `homework` questions... a hint would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`hand.split(hand)` won't work. As @home said, you should split the input string on a regular expression. Understand that the regular expression doesn't have to (and shouldn't) match the whole input string -- it should match any individual *separator*. This is how `String.split` works when passed a regular expression -- each place where the regular expression matches is taken as a separator, and the parts *between matches* are returned as an array.

So: Try to write a regular expression which will match any one separator character. Then, check that the returned array has the right number of elements. If the array is called `hand`, you can use `hand.length` for that.